# SDK 5.0 RecyclerView could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm testing the new API 21, I try to create a RecyclerView but I'm stuck with a dependency problem.

The error look like that

[image]

my layout  :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.agonist.samplify"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

I don't know what to do. I tried to clean/build the project but it stay here. Any idea ?

EDIT : Finnaly it's only an IDE preview problems. During execution everything works

Comment: this error occurs in IDE preview ?

Comment: Yes. But on execution I get NullPointer on my mRecyclerView

Comment: Is it any help if you use _buildToolsVersion 21.0.0_ or _21.0.1_ ?

Comment: `on execution I get NullPointer on my mRecyclerView`: both errors are probably un-related.

Comment: Well the error occurs on IDE preview, but now on execution I have no problems. so ... Just preview problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new RecyclerView does not yet work in Studio. Google are working on a fix. ([Open Issue 72117](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72117))

Comment: It works now - you will need to follow deepanshu steps from google: "Just in case people are still wondering, you should update to the latest SDK platform for API 22 via the SDK Manager, and update to the latest recycler view by updating the Support repository via the SDK Manager, and in your build.gradle file to use the latest version (22.0.0)"

Answer (score 1):

Your API and RecyclerView version should be same

Sync Gradle like :

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

And

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    }
```